# How can I invoke a prototype function inside of a function object it b

Tags: javascript

```
var func_obj = function() {
    console.log('wat');
    this.my_proto_method();
};

func_obj.prototype.my_proto_method = function() {
    console.log('how do I programming');
};

​func_obj();​
```

I'm trying to get the above code to work. From what I've read this should work, not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Also setup a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mateuszwijas/DBYfy/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access prototype object/method with `this` you have to create new instance of func_obj. If you want to access prototype methods withod instance then you have to use prototype property as  `func_obj.prototype.my_proto_method()`.

```
var func_obj = function() {
    console.log('wat');
    this.my_proto_method();
   // if called without new then access prototype as : func_obj.prototype.my_proto_method()
};

func_obj.prototype.my_proto_method = function() {
    console.log('how do I programming');
};

​new func_obj();​
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to prefix your call to func_obj with the new prefix:

```
var func_obj = function() {
    console.log('wat');
    this.my_proto_method();
};

func_obj.prototype.my_proto_method = function() {
    console.log('how do I programming');
};

​var foo = new func_obj();​
```

Comment: Thanks, I marked the other guys answer correct because of his answer about invoking without the new instance.